# Why do these two functions have different results?(Sorry, I don't know how to describe them)

Tags: javascript, iife

I have 2 question

1. What is the difference between `counter1()` and `counter1()()`?
   Isn't counter1 already the function name? Why the second `()`?
2. Why counter2 can memorize the value?

Here is my code:

```
const counter1 = function(){
  let initValue = 0
  return function(){
    initValue++;
    return initValue
  }
}

const counter2 = (function(){
  let initValue = 0
  return function(){
    initValue++;
    return initValue
  }
})()

console.log(counter1());
console.log(counter1()());
console.log(counter1()());
console.log(counter2());
console.log(counter2());
```

**Here is the output**:

[image]

Comment: this will help you  https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/13647574

Comment: In simper words, `counter1` is function which will return another function. `counter2` is [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) function which will invoke immediately and returns inner function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`counter1` is a function that returns a function, or what is called a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).

For the ease of discussion, let `innerCounter1` be the name of the return value of `counter1`. So the following code is equivalent to what you have in your example.

```
 const counter1 = function(){
   let initValue = 0
   const innerCounter1 = function(){
     initValue++;
     return initValue
   }
   return innerCounter1;
 }
```

> Isn't counter1 already the function name? Why the second ()?

Yes, `counter1` is a function, but it also returns a function. By naming the return value `innerCounter1`, I hope it's clear that when you call `counter1()`, the value you get is `innerCounter1`. And when you call `innerCounter1()`, the value you get is the number `initValue`. So `counter1()()` is getting the value of `innerCounter1` and calling that inner function in one short expression.

> Why counter2 can memorize the value?

When a function is created (`innerCounter1` in your example), and the function references value defined outside of the function (`initValue` in your example), a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) is created, which you can intuitively understand as "memorizing" the variable. Both the functions `counter1()` and `counter2` remembers the value, but the thing to note here is that each time `counter1()` is called, the local variables (`initValue` and `innerCounter1`) are independent. For example:

```
let counter1A = counter1();
let counter1B = counter1();

counter1A(); // 1
counter1A(); // 2
counter1B(); // 1
counter1B(); // 2
```

In other words, `counter1A` and `counter1B` are remembering a separate `initValue` variable, so calling one doesn't affect the other.

And this definition of `counter2`: `let counter2 = counter1();`, is equivalent to yours above with the anonymous function syntax, so it should be clear that what's happening is exactly the same as `counter1A` I explained above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's really detailed. Also thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

In `JS` you can return a function from a `function` which then can be used anywhere you want, add to that: that returned function can still access the variables where it was defined(can access its lexical scope variables) this feature is called closures.

Please read the comment with code carefully

```js
const counter1 = function () {
    let initValue = 0
    return function () {
        initValue++;
        return initValue
    }
}
/**
 * is the same as
 */
function counter1() {
    let initValue = 0

    /** this function is returned */
    return function () {
        /** 
         * and can access the variable `initValue` at run time because at auth time its scope is inside 
         * the `counter1` scope where the variable is defined in
         * (because inner scope can access outer scope defined in them)
         * 
         */
        initValue++;
        return initValue
    }
}
/**
 * as for using counter1
 * in each time we call the `counter1` we get a reference to the inner anonymous function that has 
 * access to that variable but in each call we have new `initValue` variable that's why 
 * no matter how many times you call `counter1` you keep getting the same result because you have new 
 * `initValue` for each call 
 */





const counter2 = (function () {
    let initValue = 0
    return function () {
        initValue++;
        return initValue
    }
})()
/**
 * this form of defining a function and immediately executing it called IIEF(Immediately invoked function expression)
 * 
 * what this code is executed you have counter2 which is equal to the inner function returned from the outer function expression
 * 
 */

// naming anonymous functions for easing
const counter2 = (function IIFE_counter2() {

    let initValue = 0

    return function counter2_returned_function() {
        initValue++;
        return initValue
    }
})()

/**
 * no counter2 = counter2_returned_function
 *
 * so
 * 1- it can access `initValue` each time it's called
 * 2- for each call of counter2 we are not creating new instance of `IIFE_counter2` instead we just call the inner
 * `counter2_returned_function` which still have the old value of `initValue` and can update it successfully
 */
```

please read from `YDKJS` to get more experience at this topic
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/ch7.md